# Using app.config file to specify startup directory for the application vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm making an application that read/write form/to files. I used

```
Public currentDir As String = FileSystem.CurrentDirectory
```

to get the current directory and the currentDir was:

```
visual studio 2013\Projects\MyProject\bin\Debug
```

How can I change this to another directory such as

```
C:\MyProject
```

and how to allow the user to change it and save his new settings?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileSystem.CurrentDirectory` is a read/write property that can be changed from your code like the following

```
FileSystem.CurrentDirectory = value
```

So let the user pass this value as parameter or change it from a setting form

**UPDATE**

You can create a New String Setting In your project and use it to achieve your goal:

1. Go to My Project Window

[image]

2. Go to Settings Tab and add your Setting like shown in the picture below

*Example Setting name: `MyDefaultPath`*

[image]

3. You can let the user change this variable from a setting form using this code:

   My.Settings.MyDefaultPath = txtValue
   My.Settings.Save()
4. Access Your Application Events Class From My project Window

[image]

5. And you can assign this value to `FileSystem.CurrentDirectory` on Application Startup

   ```
   Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices

   Namespace My

       Partial Friend Class MyApplication
           Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

               My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory = My.Settings.MyDefaultPath

           End Sub


       End Class

   End Namespace
   ```

Read more on the link provided in @VisualVincent Comment

Comment: Ok, if the user passed a value how to save it for the next time as default startup directory?

Comment: @AreejQadomi : Look into [**`My.Settings`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx).